# Code can not compile when I try to use RxJava 2 with Room

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to use RxJava 2 with Room ORM, but my code can not compile when I try to use RxJava 2.
[image]

Here is the code from Contacts Dao.

```
@Dao
public interface ContactsDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM contact")
Flowable<List<Contact>> getAll();

@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
void insert(Contact contact);

}
```

How I can solve this?

EDIT:

When I change to subscribeWith, I get this error:
[image]

There is no[image] DisposableSubscriber.

Answer (score 2):

Since RxJava2 implements the Reactive-Streams standard, `subscribe` returns `void`.

For convenience the method `subscribeWith` was added for the `Flowable` type which returns the disposable it was provided, which will make your code function as you expect.

Comment: When I change to subscribeWith it still shows the same error.

Comment: Use the `DisposableSubscriber` base class instead of `FlowableSubscriber`

Comment: Yup, `DisposableSubscriber` it is

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I can not  use a new instance of DisposableSubscribe inside subscribe method. I will edit question with a new image.

Answer (score 1):

You should take different overloading of the subscribe method.

```
  CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
  compositeDisposable.add(Observable.just(new String()).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String s) throws Exception {

            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

            }
        }));
```

Instead of subscribing it with an `Observer`, try subscribing it with `Consumer`s for `onNext()` and `onError()`. Also there is overloaded method for `onComplete()` with `Action`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    compositeDisposable.add(Flowable.just("blah").subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
```

This should work, so in your case it should be

```
disposable.add(Db.with(context).getContactsDao().findAll()
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<List<Contact>>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onNext(List<Contact> contacts) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable t) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onComplete() {

                   }    
               });
```